# Can anybody volunteer to test my Android App: Cividroid - A CiviCRM companion on Android!?

Tags: api, contacts, extension, developer, mobile

I am working on an Android App for CiviCRM: Cividroid - A CiviCRM companion on Android! as a GSoC 2015 project.

I am not a regular CiviCRM user and hence I don't have a live environment to test the current state of the App. I only have a local server set-up with some dummy data to test the features.

Is there anyone who would like to volunteer to help me test the App? I plan to push subsequent .apks based on the feedback in about 24 hours since the reception of a feedback, so I am also looking for some CiviCRM user who could constantly give me feedbacks.

The .apk, screenshots, features planned, everything you require is on this forum thread - https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36037.0

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I will get one of our team who has Android and knows Civi to do some testing and feedback for you.

Comment: That will be fantastic, @petednz-fuzion ! I have already got in touch with a  CiviCRM user and got all the feedback necessary. In 2 days, I will have the close to final product, it would be great to receive feedback on how the App works on a live environment.

Comment: @IJP, sounds like a great project. I will be happy to participate in testing it.

Comment: Awesome! I will have the near complete App in around 2 days, let me know how can I notify you, @YossiCrm !

Comment: yossicrm@gmail.com

Comment: I'm interested - clark.andy@gmail.com

Comment: peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz

Comment: Hey IJP, this is a worthy cause, but not a good Stack Exchange question. I think it should be closed and the discussion moved to other places, e.g. the CiviCRM forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't require an answer. It's a call for volunteering and feedback. Probably more appropriate in the CiviCRM forum.